# Shouldn't text to columns convert to text for MS Access when FieldInfo is set correctly in TextToColumns?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Hello I am iterating through all of my columns in an Excel workbook and TextToColumns'ing them so MS Access will bring them in as the data type that I want; however, it doesn't seem to be working for one should-be short text field.

The field in question has the field name "test" then 10 blank cells then the text "test" in rows 11 - 13 then blanks again etc. I.e. a lot of blank cells and a few short text strings.

```
With w.sheet("x")

  'I go through some logic to set variables c to a column number and
  'iFormatType to either 2 for text, which is what I use for the "test" field, or 1 for general

.Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, r.Column), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(1, iFormatType), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

end with
```

As mentioned in the comments iFormatType = 2 for field "test" when I step through it.

Later, I import the workbook into MS Access like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tbl_DatedModel_" & sSomeVariableHere, "some file path here", True
```

Field "test" should be a text field and it is a double. What am I doing wrong? Or is this just a limitation and I should move to using Schema.ini files (which I have not used)?

I have also tried this by manually importing it via the MS Access ribbon controls and I get the same result.

Here is a related questions for more background: [vba Excel to Access: zero length string to Null number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947160/vba-excel-to-access-zero-length-string-to-null-number)

Comment: Not sure if Access works the same way but when using ADO against an Excel sheet the column types are guessed from the first eight rows and a tie results in a numeric type being chosen - see the "A Caution about Mixed Data Types" section [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819) The workaround in ADO is to ensure that at least five of the first eight rows contain the desired type of data (text, in this case). Not sure if this will also work in Access

Comment: @barrowc - The only way to override that "first 8 rows" rule is to have a schema.ini file?

Comment: I think schema.ini only works for text files but you could give it a try. It might be easier to export the Excel worksheet to a CSV file and then use schema.ini with the CSV file. The reference for schema.ini is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)